# Manim: Animating row of matrix

Tags: python, manim

I would like to animate a Latex array like this one

```latex
\begin{matrix}
A & B& C \\
A & B& D \\
A & B& F \\
A & KASHDAKSJHD& F 
\end{matrix}
```

such that manim starts with the first row, transforms it into the second row with `TransformMatchingTex` and so on.

It is important, that the matrix is not split into single rows with `MathTex` as the overall spacing is important.

Comment: Why doesn't Manim's `Matrix` class work?

Comment: I did not find any solutions for how to animate a Matrix in this way. It is supposed to be animated iteratively, such that the viewer only sees one row at a time that transforms into the next one.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a simpler way to do this, if using MathTex is a requisite.

After rendering the matrix as a `MathTex()` object, I then "extracted" the subobjects to make groups with the elements (characters) of each cell.

Unfortunately this has to be done "manually", because in the resulting `MathTex` object every subobject is simply a character or symbol, and the matrix structure is lost. I know that the first three characters are the first row of the matrix, etc. But the las one is trickier, because not all elements in the matrix have the same number of characters.

So, the "extraction" of these objects can be done like this:

```py
        m = MathTex(r"\begin{matrix}"
                    r"A & B & C \\"
                    r"A & B & D \\"
                    r"A & B & F \\"
                    r"A & KASHDAKSJHD & F\\"
                    r"\end{matrix}")
        rows = [ m[0][i*3:i*3+3] for i in range(3) ]
        rows.append([m[0][9], m[0][10:-1], m[0][-1]])
```

So in the end `rows` has 4 elements (the rows of the matrix) and each one is a list of 3 elements (the columns of the matrix), and each element is a list of VMObjects (the letters or symbols of the element)

With this list prepared, we can transform each element in the next one, via a loop:

```py
        self.play(Write(rows[0]))
        for i in range(1, len(rows)):
            self.wait()
            current_row = rows[i]
            previous_row = rows[i-1]
            self.play(
               *[ReplacementTransform(cur_elem, next_elem)
                 for cur_elem, next_elem in zip(previous_row, current_row)]
            )
```

to get this result:

[image: Animation]

**Note** If you want to keep visible the already built rows, use `cur_elem.copy()` instead of `cur_elem` as first parameter of `ReplacementTransform()`. In this case the result will be:

[image: Anim2]

### Update

Of course, all can be greatly simplified if you use `Matrix()` instead of `MathTex()`. But in this case you have to manually tweak the `h_buff` parameter, because otherwise the central cell of the last row will overwrite the other rows.

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        m = Matrix(
            [["A", "B", "C"],
             ["A", "B", "D"],
             ["A", "B", "F"],
             ["A", "KASHDAKSJHD", "F"]],
             h_buff=3,
             element_alignment_corner=ORIGIN,
        )
        self.add(m.get_brackets())
        rows = m.get_rows()
        self.play(Write(rows[0]))
        prev_row = rows[0]
        for row in rows[1:]:
            self.wait()
            self.play(
                ReplacementTransform(prev_row.copy(), row),
            )
            prev_row = row

        self.wait()
```

In this case the result is:

[image: Matrix]